# Hyperplanes Componants

Tags: linear-algebra

Hyperplane: Ax + By + Cz = D
Question: I assume D for a specific hyperplane will be constant in all equations for that Hyperplane.  Am I right?
Thank you

Comment: $2Ax+2By+2Cz=2D$ would be the same hyperplane.

Comment: But the Scalar 2 in the above equation should be the same for A, B and C right?

Comment: And the norm for the hyperplane will still be {A, B, C}  right?

Comment: Neither the scalar(2), nor the A,B,C and x,y,z could be 0...right?

Comment: There’s no such thing as “the norm[al].” There’s an infinite number of them, all nonzero scalar multiples of each other.

Comment: No. My understanding is if Hyperplane W = Ax+By+Cz=D then the set of scalars {A, B, C} 'normal' to W and it is perpendicular to W with the dot product of 0!

Comment: No! My understanding is If W is a Hyperplane that is Ax+By+Cz=D, then the set of scalars {A, B, C} is 'Normal' to W with the dot product of 0!